# Google web application Oauth2 redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: vb.net, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

I'm trying to exchange the authorize code with token and all the time I receive "redirect_uri_mismatch".
Now,  all url that are written in the console are identical to the redirect_url that I send in the body of the POST web request,

this is the code(vb) after receiving the response with the authorize code:

```
        Dim strCode As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("code")
        Dim getTokenBody As String                   
        getTokenBody = "code=" & HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(strCode) & _
                                "&client_id=" & HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(AppStaticData.Config.GoogleClientID.Value) & _
                                "&client_secret=" & HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(AppStaticData.Config.GoogleClientSecret.Value) & _
                                "&redirect_uri=" & HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode("http://localhost:53706/user/authenticate") & _
                                "&scope=" & _
                                "&grant_type=authorization_code"
        Dim buffer As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(getTokenBody)
        Dim url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
        request.Method = "POST"
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        request.ContentLength = buffer.Length

        Dim strm As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        strm.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        strm.Close()
        Try
            Dim res As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()               
        Catch ex As WebException
            Dim a = ex.Response
            Dim wr As Net.HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(a, Net.HttpWebResponse)
            Dim s = New StreamReader(wr.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd               
        End Try
```

Comment: Is the url in the trusted list for your application?

Comment: @the_lotus yes it is

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your return uri to the list of redirect uri's in the developer console for your application.

[image: console img]

(here's the link if the screen shot doesn't work https://www.dropbox.com/s/lgjm1zgk8qeft00/console.png?dl=0)

At the bottom of the screen shot you see edit settings. Click that and add your uri to the `AUTHORIZED REDIRECT URIS` section.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, all urls are listed!

Comment: More specifically, are you using the *same* redirect uri both when requesting the initial authorization *and* when exchanging the code? Using different URLs for the same grant, even if both declared in the developer console, will cause issues.

Comment: @SteveBazyl can you please describe more what you saying here.. because I am having the same problem. Thank you.